# Laptop keeps waking up after suspend

Tags: keyboard, suspend, power-management

I am having a hard time figuring out what causes my laptop to wake up instantly after suspending. I ran `systemctl suspend` and my laptop just woke up instantly.

I suspect that there is a physical fault on the keyboard, but I am not sure because it is not stated on `journalctl` that my keyboard caused the wake up.

I also have tried adding `echo "EHC1" > /proc/acpi/wakeup` to `/etc/rc.local` with no avail.

I am using Elementary OS 0.4 Loki and my laptop is Lenovo G40-70 with Intel Celeron 2957U.

Here is my `journalctl` report

http://textuploader.com/dsa90

Any solution to make my laptop suspend as it should?

Sincerely,

Ismail

UPDATE: I have tried disabling the Wake-on-LAN using `ethtool` to no avail. But I have sucsessfully hibernated my laptop using `systemctl hibernate` (though I don't know why it asked root permission).

Comment: You might find clues in '/etc/systems/logind.conf' but I don't know anything about your OS and its interface sorry.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Tried opening that file, nothing was found. Elementary OS is based on ubuntu 16.04, so I guessed the soulution would be the same as Ubuntu. :/

Comment: Ahhh. So many based on Ubuntu....

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this is a known problem with Intel.  I can't find the source now, but am sure that I read that there is an issue with the processors waking due to small movements.  Seems odd to me, but the problem occurs with Windows laptops as well, so I suspect is not an Ubuntu / Linux issue.

Comment: I have the same issue with Ubuntu 22.04.1 installed on a Macbook Pro Retina 2013 model. Hardware should not be the issue because power management worked perfect when MacOs was installed.